# How to solve the 410:Gone error in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am trying to make a program that searches amazon using the amazon simple-product API but it is showing some HTTP 410:Gone error.
Here is the code.

```
from amazon.api import AmazonAPI
amazon = AmazonAPI('A********************A', 'X**************************m', 
'1*******************0')
a=input(':')
results = amazon.search(Keywords = a, SearchIndex = "Books")
for item in results:
     print (item.title, item.isbn, item.price_and_currency)
```

Now this is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\susheel\Desktop\booksearch.py", line 12, in <module>
for item in results:
File "C:\Users\susheel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\amazon\api.py", line 
544, in __iter__
for page in self.iterate_pages():
File "C:\Users\susheel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\amazon\api.py", line 
561, in iterate_pages
yield self._query(ItemPage=self.current_page, **self.kwargs)
File "C:\Users\susheel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\amazon\api.py", line 
573, in _query
response = self.api.ItemSearch(ResponseGroup=ResponseGroup, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\susheel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\bottlenose\api.py", 
line 273, in __call__
response = self._call_api(api_url,
File "C:\Users\susheel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\bottlenose\api.py", 
line 235, in _call_api
return urllib2.urlopen(api_request, timeout=self.Timeout)
File "C:\Users\susheel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in 
urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Users\susheel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in 
open
response = meth(req, response)
File "C:\Users\susheel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 640, in 
http_response
response = self.parent.error(
File "C:\Users\susheel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in 
error
return self._call_chain(*args)
File "C:\Users\susheel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in 
_call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "C:\Users\susheel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in 
http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 410: Gone
```

Please help me out.

Comment: *The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 410 Gone client error response code indicates that access to the target resource is no longer available at the origin server and that this condition is likely to be permanent.* Maybe the `Books` search index isn't correct. Have you tried other indices?

Comment: Books indices is correct.

Comment: This python package is long since no longer maintained and attempts to use an Amazon API that stopped existing months ago.